# Variable can't be resolved to a field

Tags: java, class

I am trying to update a enqueue function of a *queue* class so that it enqueue a stack item (nrm LIFO stack) according to its size.
But when I try to use the variable for the size of the stack (N) it says variable can't be resolved or it is not a field. All fields and methods are public in all classes.

```
public void add(SpecialStack SpecialStack) {
    Node<SpecialStack> oldlast = last;
    last = new Node<SpecialStack>();
    last.astack = SpecialStack;
    int a = last.astack.N;
    last.next = null;

    if (isEmpty())
        first = last;
    else
        oldlast.next = last;
    N++;
}
```

This is the function who is problematic, and the class which i want to add:

```
public class SpecialStack {
    public Node <Integer> first;
    public int N;

    public static class Node <Integer> {
        public Integer value;
        public Node next;

        Node (Integer a) {
            value = a;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We find that code is better than English sometimes. You may [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36225474/edit) to include some.

Comment: As much as I'd love to have mind-reading powers, unfortunately, I do not, so please post your code.

Comment: Even without seeing code, if the compiler says that `N` can't be resolved or is not a field; **then** it *really* can't be resolved or is not a field.

Comment: You are doing something wrong. Most likely you are not using the right instance to access those fields.

Comment: I am sure i am doing something wrong. The thing is it is a hw , and i can't post the code here , because it might be taken for plagiarism.

Comment: @dasdasd I will not let the evil lawyers do anything to you. I am your personal protector. Now post your code.

Answer (score 1):

`N` exists inside `SpecialStack`, not inside `WhateverClassDeclaresTheAddMethod`, yet you try to do `N++` inside `WhateverClassDeclaresTheAddMethod`. To fix the compile problem you would need to do `last.astack.N++` instead, but that doesn't make sense because that's the size of the `SpecialStack`, not the size of the `Queue`.

You really need an `N` inside of `Queue` so you can increment that.

(Note: please don't name your variables and fields using something that starts with an upper case letter. That makes most of us cringe.)

As for the problem on `int a= last.astack.N`... you haven't declared `last.astack` to be of type `SpecialStack`. You've made it something else, something more general, that doesn't have an `N`. So even though the object stored in `last.astack` *is* a `SpecialStack` and *has* an `N`, the compiler can't tell because it can't see the instance at compile time.

Comment: Special Stack is the second class, N is there.

Comment: Do you have any idea what can cause the problem?

Comment: fixed that part, but still the N of the SpecialStack is un accessable

Comment: What exactly is the compiler error message? On which line?

Comment: at int a= last.astack.N

Comment: Updated again. Please check.

Comment: Thanks for the advice , i would ask if there is a method to force it to act as a SpeacialStack?

Comment: That's probably the wrong approach. You're not doing anything with `a`. Why do you need `N`? Alternatively, what type _is_ `astack`? Could you add a `size()` method to that?